# Prove the equality $\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\sum_{k=0}^nb_kx^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\sum_{i=0}^ka_ib_{k-i}\right)x^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm currently trying to show that this following equality holds:
$$\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\sum_{k=0}^nb_kx^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\sum_{i=0}^ka_ib_{k-i}\right)x^k$$

I've expanded LHS and RHS
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\sum_{k=0}^nb_kx^k=&\ a_0x^0 \left( b_0x^0 + b_1x^1+ \cdots + b_nx^n\right)\\
+&\ a_1x^1 \left( b_0x^0 + b_1x^1+ \cdots + b_nx^n\right)\\
+&\ a_2x^2 \left( b_0x^0 + b_1x^1+ \cdots + b_nx^n\right)\\
\vdots& \\ 
+&\ a_nx^n \left( b_0x^0 + b_1x^1+ \cdots + b_nx^n\right)\\
\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\sum_{i=0}^ka_ib_{k-i}\right)x^k=&\ x^0 (a_0b_k+a_1b_{k-1}+\cdots+a_kb_0)\\
+&\ x^1 (a_0b_k+a_1b_{k-1}+\cdots+a_kb_0)\\ 
+&\ x^2 (a_0b_k+a_1b_{k-1}+\cdots+a_kb_0)\\ 
\vdots\\
+&\ x^n (a_0b_k+a_1b_{k-1}+\cdots+a_kb_0)\\ 
\end{align*}

which appears to be true, but I'm struggling to find a way to prove that it is true. Is there some factoring trick I can use on the sums?

Comment: Just notice the coefficient of $x^k$ on both sides.

Comment: shouldnt upper limit on degree of $x$ be $2n$ on rhs?

Comment: discrete convolution

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\sum_{k=0}^nb_kx^k\\
=(a_0x^0+a_1x^1+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n)(b_0x^0+b_1x^1+b_2x^2+\cdots+b_nx^n)$

Hence the coefficient of $x^k$ is
$$a_0b_k+a_1b_{k-1}+a_2b_{k-2}+\cdots+a_kb_0=\sum_{i=0}^k a_ib_{k-i}$$

Therefore you get $$\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\sum_{k=0}^nb_kx^k=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (\sum_{i=0}^k a_ib_{k-i})x^k$$ The equality is proven.